# Why am I getting kicked out of my chroot?

Tags: chroot

I enter a chroot, source a script to initialize my git user (`source init_my_chroot`) and then seem to be too sensitive to getting kicked out of my chroot.

```
install: cannot create regular file ‘/path/to/testfile’: No such file or directory
make: *** [my-rule] Error 1
me@vm:~$
```

Is something calling `exit`?

`init_my_chroot`:

```
set -e

main() {
  mount -t proc proc /proc || true
  mount -t devpts none /dev/pts || true
  git config alias.lg "log --oneline --decorate --all --graph"
  eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
}

main "$@"
```

Comment: does your file `init_my_chroot` have `exit` or `logout` anywhere in it?  e.g. if it detects that `make` failed?

Comment: @casey, added a slimmed down init script

Comment: `set -e` means that any command that gets an error triggers an exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set -e` means that the shell should exit immediately if any command exits with a non-zero status (except in some contexts that explicitly test exit status, such as the condition of an `if` or `while`).

If you want the option to be in effect only while `main()` is running, you can do:

```
set -e
main "$@"
set +e
```